# Remove shipping info for free shipping method on WooCommerce email notifications

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, orders, email-notifications

When the customer order is placed, I would like if free shipping has been used, to **`remove shipping info`** from the order confirmation mail to the customer.

Is it possible to achieve this?

Answer (score 2):

This is possible with this custom hooked function *(but from all email notifications)*:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_get_order_item_totals', function( $total_rows, $order, $tax_display ){

    // Only for "Free Shipping" method
    if( ! $order->has_shipping_method('free_shipping') || is_account_page() || is_wc_endpoint_url( 'order-received' ) )
        return $total_rows; 

    unset($total_rows['shipping']);

    return $total_rows;
}, 11, 3 );
```

*Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or theme) or also in any plugin file.*

This code is tested and works.